# How can a registry that is set to open an application identify if it's already open and bring it to front if so?

Tags: angular, vb6, registry

Long story short:
I have an Angular web application and I need to integrate it with an existing VB application.

There are some events in the web app that should launch the VB one and provide some information depending on the event.

I have found a way of doing so by using a registry, and calling it from the web app with the required params.

The main problem that I encounter and I'm trying to look for a solution is the following:
Is there a way where the registry call does not open a new instance of the VB app if it's already open - and brings to front the existing one, while passing the parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the Windows Registry? Or are you referring to something else? Maybe if you can add a little more detail about what your app is already doing to start the VB app it would be a bit clearer.

Comment: If you control the code for the vb app, when it starts up, it can check for another instance running and switch to it. Or it could shutdown the prior instance and continue with the work itself.